# Definite integral over one variable in a function with two variables in Scipy

Tags: python, scipy, numerical-integration, quad

I am trying to calculate the definite integral of a function with multiple variables over just one variable in scipy. 
This is kind of like what my code looks like-

```
from scipy.integrate import quad
import numpy as np
def integrand(x,y):
    return x*np.exp(x/y)

quad(integrand, 1,2, args=())
```

And it returns this type error:

```
TypeError: integrand() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)
```

However, it works if I put a number into args. But I don't want to, because I want y to remain as y and not a number. Does anyone know how this can be done?

EDIT: Sorry, don't think I was clear. I want the end result to be a function of y, with y still being a symbol.

Comment: quad is for numerical integration, so can only be done for a definite value of y (you could use a partial function in this case). Did you want symbolic integration? In that case look at sympy.

Comment: I want the answer to be a function of y. Can I use sympy (as in y=Symbol('y') in combination with scipy?

Comment: I don't think so, scipy is purely numeric (but try it - maybe the symbol propagates through); you should use the integration within sympy http://docs.sympy.org/dev/modules/integrals/integrals.html

Comment: Yeah, I tried using them in combination, it doesn't work. But won't I have the same problem with sympy, just that now it will only do symbolic integration? I still need 'x' to be integrated.

Comment: No: sympy really can do real definite (and indefinite) integration, returning numerical values for coefficients of the remaining unknown symbol, in this instance y.

Comment: Thank you, using Sympy only works for this example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to mdurant, here's what works:

```
from sympy import integrate, Symbol, exp
from sympy.abc import x
y=Symbol('y')
f=x*exp(x/y)
integrate(f, (x, 1, 2))
```

Answer:

```
-(-y**2 + y)*exp(1/y) + (-y**2 + 2*y)*exp(2/y)
```

Comment: Hi, in the above code, y is a symbol. If we set `int_f = integrate(f, (x, 1, 2))`, in principle, `int_f` is a function of `y`, how can we get the value of `int_f` if we set different values of `y`? Thanks~

Answer (score 3):

You probably just want the result to be a function of `y` right?:

```
from scipy.integrate import quad
import numpy as np
def integrand(x,y):
    return x*np.exp(x/y)

partial_int = lambda y: quad(integrand, 1,2, args=(y,))
print partial_int(5)
#(2.050684698584342, 2.2767173686148355e-14)
```

Comment: Can I print this so it will show the result as a function of y?

Answer (score 0):

The best you can do is use functools.partial, to bind what arguments you have for the moment. But one fundamentally cannot numerically integrate a definite integral if you havnt got the entire domain specified yet; in that case the resulting expression will necessarily still contain symbolic parts, so the intermediate result isn't numerical.

Comment: I want the result to contain y as a symbol, sorry if that wasn't clear.

Comment: numerical integration isn't going to do it, if that wasn't clear ;)

Answer (score 0):

(Assuming that you are talking about computing the definite integral over `x` given a specific, fixed value of `y`.)

You could use a lambda:

```
quad(lambda x:integrand(x, 10), 1, 2, args=())
```

or `functools.partial()`:

```
quad(functools.partial(integrand, y=10), 1, 2, args=())
```

Comment: I want the answer to be a function of y-sorry if that wasn't clear.

Answer (score 0):

```
from scipy.integrate import quad
import numpy as np
def integrand(x,y):
    return x*np.exp(x/y)

vec_int = np.vectorize(integrand)
y = np.linspace(0, 10, 100)
vec_int(y)
```